# Python Score not accumulating

Tags: python, python-3.4

## PROBLEM:

I have written a python game based around guessing a number that the computer is thinking of. I have added in a scoring system to that depending on how many lives you have left when you get the right answer you get points. There is also a play again feature and my idea was that when you press n when asked to play again your score since the program was opened is printed before it quits. However there's a bug in my code and when it prints the score you only get the score from the last game you played showing for instance as shown in the picture you should have 10 points at the end but it prints 0. Please help with this I've been stuck for hours. My code is included below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEoy8.png

## CODE:

```
#imports required modules
import random
#score set as global variable with the value 0
global score
score = 0
#lower number set as global and value of user input
global low
low = int(input('Lowest number: '))
#lower number set a global and value of user input
global up
up = int(input('Hightest number: '))

print('\nI\'m thinking of a number guess what it is...\n')

#main game code
def main():
    global low
    global up
    #generates number at random between the users two inputs
    comp_num = random.randint(low,up)
    #score set as global variable within function
    global score
    #lives created
    lives = 3
    while lives >= 1:
        #player guesses
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        if comp_num == guess:
            #if correct says well done
            print('\nWell Done! You guessed Correctly!\n')
            #1 live left player gets 5 points
            if lives == 1:
                score == score + 5
                print('\nYou scored 5 points!')
            #2 lives left player gets 10 points
            elif lives == 2:
                score = score + 10
                print('\nYou scored 10 points!')
            #3 lives left player gets 15 points
            elif lives == 3:
                score = score + 15
                print('\nYou scored 15 points!')
            break
        elif comp_num >= guess:
            #if guess is too low tells player
            #one live taken for incorrect guess
            lives = lives -1
            print('\nToo low!\n')
            #player is told how many lives they have left
            print('You guessed incorrectly. You have',lives,'live(s) remaining.\n')
            if lives == 0:
                    #if player guesses incorrectly they get told the correct awnser
                    print('The number I was thinking of was...',comp_num,'!\n')
        elif comp_num <= guess:
            #if guess is too high tells player
            #one live taken for incorrect guess
            lives = lives -1
            print('\nToo high!\n')
            #player is told how many lives they have left
            print('You guessed incorrectly. You have',lives,'live(s) remaining.\n')
            if lives == 0:
                    #if player guesses incorrectly they get told the correct awnser
                    print('The number I was thinking of was...',comp_num,'!\n')

def end():
    #asks player if they want to play again
    play_again = input('Would you like to play again?[Y/N] ')
    while play_again.lower() == 'y':
        #if they do game resets and plays again
        if play_again.lower() == 'y':
            comp_num = random.randint(1,10)
            print('\nI\'m thinking of a number guess what it is...\n')
            main()
            play_again = input('Would you like to play again?[Y/N] ')
            if play_again.lower() == 'n':
                break
    if play_again.lower() == 'n':
        #if they don't game ends
        print('\nYou scored',score,'points!')
        #score printed before exit
        input('Press enter to exit')
        exit()

#calls main section of game
main()

#calls end of game to give option of playing again and resetting game
end()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a type error:

```
  if lives == 1:
            score == score + 5
```

I guess that should have been:

```
  if lives == 1:
            score = score + 5
```

Comment: Also using the shorthand operator equals expression will reduce the likelihood of doing this. `score += 5`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been staring at this for hours!

Comment: @DannyStaple I will try using this in the future to avoid further issues. Thank you